# how to make a usb read-only with python?

Tags: python, security, pycharm, usb, readonly

I am trying to make a usb read-only using pycharm. 
I tried using codes that I found and although they worked on regular folders they didn't work with the usb directory. please help me :)

```
import win32security
import ntsecuritycon as con
import getpass

file_name = r'F:\\' #THE USB


sd = win32security.GetFileSecurity(file_name, win32security.DACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION)
dacl = sd.GetSecurityDescriptorDacl()


ace_count = dacl.GetAceCount()
print('Ace count:', ace_count)

for i in range(0, ace_count):
    dacl.DeleteAce(0)


userx, domain, type = win32security.LookupAccountName("", "my.user")


dacl.AddAccessAllowedAceEx(win32security.ACL_REVISION, 3, 1179785, userx) # Read only


sd.SetSecurityDescriptorDacl(1, dacl, 0)   # may not be necessary
win32security.SetFileSecurity(file_name, win32security.DACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION, sd)
```

Comment: Only NTFS has support for ACLs. FAT has not, and is usually used on USB portable drives.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after digging more in the net and totally changing my approach to this problem I was able finally to make my usb read only and and vice versa. hope you will find my solution useful.
I found different sources so this is not really "my soultion", its different codes edited and adjusted to my needs.

```
import _winreg
import usb

REG_PATH = r"SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\StorageDevicePolicies"

# Equivalent of the _IO('U', 20) constant in the linux kernel.
USBDEVFS_RESET = ord('U') << (4 * 2) | 20

def set_reg(name, value):
        try:
                _winreg.CreateKey(_winreg.HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, REG_PATH)
                print "1"
                registry_key = _winreg.OpenKey(_winreg.HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, REG_PATH,0, _winreg.KEY_SET_VALUE)
                _winreg.SetValueEx(registry_key, name, 0, _winreg.REG_DWORD, value)
                _winreg.CloseKey(registry_key)
                return True
        except:
                "oops"


name = "WriteProtect"
value = 1 # 1 is read only 0 is also writable

x = set_reg(name,value) # make the usb read only or writable
print x


#reseting the usb device
my_device = usb.core.find()
my_device.reset() # reset the usb to apply the effect
```

Few Important notes:

1.this code can be splitted into 2 parts , the first makes the usb read only or vice versa the second reloads/resets the usb from within the computer.

2.you might need to create the "StorageDevicePolicies" key in the registry.

3.you might need to install libusb-win32-devel-filter-1.2.6.0.exe in orded to create the backend on the usb device.

4.this solution makes all the usb devices on the computer read only (or writable)